# Can I remove some of our disk allocation?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server, azure, azure-vm

I've started work for a new company who are using Azure for their SQL Databases.

As one of my first tasks, they've asked me if they have too much storage (expensive storage), and would like to remove (and save money) by cancelling some of their storage (disk #2 in the attached screenshot).

I have no idea if this is possible or how to do this ?[image: hard disk config as it stands]

Screenshot of the disks is attached...

Any help possible here please ?

Comment: Is that Premium (SSD) storage?  If not, you only pay for what you use, not what you've allocated.  But you can't eject disks from the pool, only add them.  If you want a smaller pool, you will need to add new disks and then move your databases over.

Comment: Sorry, continued.  If you are going to move to regular disks, make sure to attach as many as the machine will support, with at least 4 disks for each pool to maximize performance.